# How do I horizontally center a FlexLayout inside a StackLayout?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `FlexLayout` inside of a `StackLayout`:

```xml
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0,100">
    <Label
        Text="Franklin"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="Large" />
    <Label Text="Mostly Cloudy" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <Label
        Text="55°"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="Header" />

    <!-- PLEASE CENTER ME -->
    <FlexLayout>
        <Label Text="H:55°" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
        <Label Text="L:37°" />
    </FlexLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

[image: FlexLayout inside a StackLayout]

How do I center the `FlexLayout` inside the `StackLayout`?

Comment: `HorizontalOptions="Center"`

Comment: @Jason Where do I apply that attribute?

Comment: @Jason I applied that attribute to the `FlexLayout` tag. But it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a `StackLayout` in the horizontal orientation. A StackLayout gives the more natural flow of placing the elements in the page.

```xml
<!-- This part is now centered -->
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Label Text="H:55°" Padding="5,0" />
    <Label Text="L:37°" Padding="5,0" />
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `FlexLayout` in an `AbsoluteLayout`:

```xml
<!-- This part is now centered -->
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <FlexLayout>
        <Label Text="H:55°" Padding="5,0" />
        <Label Text="L:37°" Padding="5,0" />
    </FlexLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image: FlexLayout centered in StackLayout]

Note that I split your margin on the first label into padding between the two labels so that they would be centered inside the `FlexLayout`.